# python metaclass doesn't remember the new value

Tags: python, metaclass

I wrote a class Person with a metaclass Spell. In the metaclass I change an attribute and it is ok, but if i want to use this new value for another operation, it doesn't work and it use the previous value.
How can i fix this?

```
class Spell(type):
    def __new__(cls,classname,super,classdict):
        def pph( hours ): return lambda self : classdict['pay_per_hour'] * hours

        classdict['pay_per_hour'] = 12
        classdict['day_salary'] = pph(8)
    return type.__new__(cls, classname, super, classdict )

class Person(metaclass=Spell):
    def __init__(self,name,lastname,bday):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.bday = bday

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
    def get_lastname(self):
        return self._lastname
    def get_bday(self):
        return self._bday
    def __repr__(self):
        return "name: {0}, lastname: {1}, bday: {2}".format(self.name,self.lastname,self.bday)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    persona4 = Person("lugdfgca","djfosd","16 febbraio 85")
    print(persona4.pay_per_hour)
    print(persona4.day_salary())
    persona4.pay_per_hour=15
    print(persona4.pay_per_hour)
    print(persona4.day_salary())
```

The output is

```
12
96
15
96
```

but 96 is 12*8 not 15*8, why? where is the error?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to use a metaclass? There is nothing in your example that wouldn't be easier with regular base class.

Comment: i've had to use metaclass for an university exam, this is an exercise in preparation for the exam

Answer (score 2):

The lambda you created refers to the dictionary filled during class construction. Later (after class creation) changes to class variables are not reflected in it, but even if that was the case, the line `persona4.pay_per_hour = 15` assigns a new instance attribute instead of changing the class attribute. Use `self.pay_per_hour` in the functions produced by `pph` to get the value the instance in question uses at the moment.

Or, even better, do away with the metaclass. There's no reason to use them here, and as you saw, it's easy to make things less extensible than needed.

```
class Spell:
    pay_per_hour = 12
    hours_per_day = 8

    # @property # allows nicer syntax, look it up if you don't know it
    def day_salary(self):
        return hours_per_day * pay_per_hour

class Person(Spell):
    ...
```

This handles changes to pay_per_hour and hours_per_day transparently and at instance level.

Comment: This. I'm not sure what the benefit of using a metaclass in this case would be. It seems like good, old-fashioned class inheritance should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function `pph` only look up the value of `pay_per_hour` in the class dictionary, while you only override the value of `pay_per_hour` in the instance. In Python, when you lookup a value of a field of an object, it first check in the instance dictionary, then in the class dictionary (and all the super class in the mro order).

You need to change your metaclass to:

```
def __new__(cls,classname,super,classdict):
    def pph( hours ): return lambda self : self.pay_per_hour * hours

    classdict['pay_per_hour'] = 12
    classdict['day_salary'] = pph(8)
```